# EditText Event Generation after taking input from user

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to hit API when an user finishes the input in EditText. How can we do it?
I want only EditText for it.

Comment: Find how to use `TextWatcher` and try it.

Comment: first you have to determine, what does `the user finishes input` mean. What should happen? The user does not type text for certain amount of sesonds? Or hits `next/go` button??

Comment: implemnt TextWatcher and add code in its method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add these property to edit text

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Then use this code on your edit text to find when user pressed enter

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Call API      
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

OR
Use onEditorAction like this :

```
edittext.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);


etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()

                                           {
                                               @Override
                                               public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                                                   if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                                                     //call api
                                                       return true;
                                                   }
                                                   return false;
                                               }
                                           }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add TextWatcher into Edittext

   ```
   editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {  @Override
       public void  beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int
           i,  int i1, int i2) {

       }

       @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int
       i, int i1, int i2) {

                   if(charSequence.length()>2)
                   {
                     //Write code for hitting API
                   }    }

        @Override   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                                       } });
   ```

   and inside onTextChanged() method you can write your logic to hit
   API. I mean you can fix some character length and then hit API;

Comment: But this method will make API call every time input is greater than 2 in length. Let's say a user enters 10 characters and then deletes 6 characters from them. In this case, it will also make API call. How can we deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is helpful for you :

```
edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
            {
                @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
                {

                }

                @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                {
                    if(s.length()>0)
                    {

                    }

                }

                @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                {
                  //Text change done
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Thanks to all , i solve my problem this way 
edtTo.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            switch( actionId ) {
                case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                    // clear editText focus and hide 
                    edtTo.clearFocus();

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtFrom.getWindowToken(), 0);


                    Log.e("Debug","Hit Api ");
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: If any of the answers by other helped you, Please consider voting that answer and instead of posting your own answer, try to accept other's answer.